# Can I start an Intent by this method?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a conceptual idea, just assume I have 2 intents, `Intent a` and `Intent b` , which is initialised to **two** different activities. I want these intents to start, considering a dynamic data on my server.

What I mean to say is - 
I have a txt file on my server, `example.com/cmd.txt`
which contains a string -

`open a` , If this string is found, `Intent a` should start, or if `open b` is found as a string on the txt file, `Intent b` should start.

Basically my app should read the content of the text file, check the condition and open the appropriate `Intent`

Been searching answers for this.. Found it no where!

I don't know how should I approach this issue.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you know the data every time received from server?

Comment: What part of this problem is confusing you, specifically? Downloading a text file from a Web server?

Comment: The data on my webserver is dynamic, I would change it myself, whenever I want to.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I don't know how to approach it. That's the problem.

Comment: Under which situations should the app open the intent? When receiving user input? When you change the file?

Comment: How to approach *what*? Download the file. Look in the resulting `String` for your command strings. Use the Java `if` statement as a control block for creating the appropriate `Intent` based upon what command string you find. Call `startActivity()` on that `Intent`. So, I ask again: what part of this problem is confusing you, **specifically**?

Comment: @jvrodrigues: Assume that my web url `example.com/cmd.txt` contains:

`open a` , now my app should get response from the HTTP URL, check if the string is `open a` or `open b`, start an Intent accordingly.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I want to know how can I get the `command` which is on my webserver to a `String` on my `java`

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: you could make a HttpGet Request to get your txt file

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the text file using HttpConnection
    Use
    if  (String.contains("start a")){startIntent(a);}
    else if (String.contains("start b")){startIntent(b);}